# How to extract a date from a string in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Example:

```
PROMOTED AS AO 2 W.E.F. 29.07.2010
```

This line is written in a single cell. I want to extract the date `29.07.2010` in another cell in Excel.

Comment: Is the date always at the end? Is it always in the same format?

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks detail but assuming that the date is always on the right and remains in the same format (as in the last 10 characters or the cell) then you can use

```
=RIGHT(TRIM(A1),10)
```

[image]

Comment: This just gives a text string, and presumably you want to do calculations with this date as well - in that case, you should use the `VALUE` function. Also, in my locale (UK), Excel didn't recognise dates formatted with a `.` separator, so I had to use `SUBST` to change the text to dd/mm/yyyy format.